# Offset a subfigure vertical axis

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats

I have a figure made of three subfigures, one on top and two below it.
Currently the two lower figures are aligned based on the height of their caption. I need the left subfigure to be closer to the top one, as shown on the scheme below. This subfigure doesn't need a caption.

[image]

I tried things with vspace but no success (I'm still a beginner). Here is a MWE of my code :

```
\documentclass[french]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{1\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.97\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Top subfigure caption}
            \vspace{0.5cm}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\linewidth} 
            \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}% table
                \begin{axis}
                    \addplot table[x=x,y=y] {data.dat};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Table caption}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

data.dat contains

```
x y
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the same output you get. Please also clarify: Is the bottom left subfigure also supposed to get its own subcaption? Where should it be placed?

Comment: Thanks ! I edited my question in consequence. The left subfigure doesn't need a caption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optional parameter `t` is aligning the `subfigure`s regarding the top baseline of its contents (and the baseline of an image is its lower border). But this is not what you want, you want to align them regarding the upper border. For this the parameter `T` has to be used:

```
\documentclass[french]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{1\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.97\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Top subfigure caption}
            \vspace{0.5cm}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[T]{0.4\linewidth} 
            \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[T]{0.5\linewidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}% table
                \begin{axis}
                    \addplot table[x=x,y=y] {data.dat};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Table caption}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]